# Grails session-scoped Service throwing NotSerializable Exception

Tags: session, grails, serialization

I have a Grails 3 application (3.1.1) that implements a Breadcrumb system. I based it on [this plugin](https://github.com/cyrilkiller/groovy-breadcrumbs-plugin) for an earlier version of Grails.

It runs fine locally (using Grails command line command `run-app`), however, when I build and run on Tomcat 7, I get the following exception:

```
Jul 08, 2016 5:10:34 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager requestCompleted
SEVERE: Unable to serialize delta request for sessionid [6605EAC9C04DF7E2512493CABDFB1AD2]
java.io.NotSerializableException: au.packagename.BreadCrumbService
```

The above named service has a scope set to `session`, and is specified as a proxy. I have even added the `Serializable` implementation, however that does not seem to help.

```
class BreadCrumbService implements Serializable {

    static transactional = false
    static scope = 'session'
    static proxy = true

}
```

I have an `Interceptor` that uses the Service to write the current controller and action as a `Crumb` object to the session. I have added the `Serializable` implementation to the `Crumb` and `BreadCrumbType` Enum (used in the Controllers annotation) that gets written to the session.

Is anyone able to indicate to me why this might be happening (I understand the concept of Serializable) and how I might go about resolving it?

Comment: are you sure all members of BreadCrumbService are transient or Serializable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hoàng Long's comment put me the right track.

When writing the Crumb object (all of which were made Serializable) to the session, I was using a static variable in the BreadCrumbService for the session map's key.

```
session[BreadCrumbService.NAMESPACE].crumb = new Crumb()
```

When I moved this variable to the Crumb object, the issue was resolved.

Even though the Service itself hasn't being written to the session. The mere reference to a variable inside the Service in the writing to the session required the service and every member to be Serializable.